# Which image has been accessed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to know which image has been accessed or loaded to a web page at which time? For example, if my page contains one image, and the page is loaded on ten different machines, where can I find a log that tells this image has been loaded ten times? I am using nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see these requests in Nginx or Apache logs. You can count them with the help of grep and tail (if you have huge logs and need to count just a part of it).